# How to properly submit special character to Spring Restful WebService?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

i have already build a Spring Restful WebService, then i create a dynamic url. Which is here my code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamicurl/{sp}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public Map<String, String> insertsoheaderdinamis(@PathVariable("sp") String sp, HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {

    String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

    String split[] = restOfTheUrl.split("/");

    String strParam="EXEC "+ split[4] + " '";

    for (int a=5;a<split.length;a++)
    {
        strParam=strParam+split[a]+"','";   
        /*System.out.println(split[a]); */
    }

    strParam=strParam.substring(0, strParam.length()-2);


    Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();

    try {
        userService.dynamicurl(strParam);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();

        result.put("message", "Some notif");
    }

    return result;

}
```

when i trying to submit a url without "SPECIAL CHARACTER" it's completely fine. But when i have to send a url with some value with "SPECIAL CHARATER" it give me error, especially when i send "/" (SLASH). In my code i trying to convert SLASH to "," (coma) to make it to be string that i want. Here is my URL example :

Encoded version :

> http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/dynamicurl/WEB_SP_InsertPool/TRX_SOHEADER/''OPJ1401577''%2cCAST(''2014-09-06+09%3a30%3a29''+as+DATETIME)%2c''JKT-PAR''%2c''JKTB009''%2c''NNNN''%2c''urgent/noturgent''%2cCAST(''2014-09-06+09%3a30%3a29''+as+DATETIME)%2c''PARWIS''%2cNULL%2cCAST(''2014-09-13+09%3a30%3a29''+as+DATETIME)%2c''SHIMIZU''%2cNULL%2cNULL%2cNULL

Decoded version :

> http://10.1.48.243:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/dynamicurl/WEB_SP_InsertPool/TRX_SOHEADER/''OPJ1401577'',CAST(''2014-09-06
>   09:30:29'' as
>   DATETIME),''JKT-PAR'',''JKTB009'',''NNNN'',''urgent/nourgent'',CAST(''2014-09-06 09:30:29'' as
>   DATETIME),''PARWIS'',NULL,CAST(''2014-09-13 09:30:29'' as
>   DATETIME),''SHIMIZU'',NULL,NULL,NULL

in this sentences "urgent/noturgent" it have "/"(slash) value. I trying to encode the "/" (Slash) to be "%2F" then i have to replace it in my url, it don't even enter my webservice, just like its not execute in my web browser, nothing happened, if i submit my url with "/" (slash), it will be converted as "," (coma). How can i solved this issue with Special Character?

Comment: It will consider / as url parameter. Same problem occurred to me once. What you have to do is replace all the / with pipe and then give a try. It will surly work. Good day

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an encoding issue. Encoded version of your "decoded" one should be:

> http://10.1.48.243:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/dynamicurl/WEB_SP_InsertPool/TRX_SOHEADER/%27%27OPJ1401577%27%27%2CCAST%28%27%272014-09-06+09%3A30%3A29%27%27+as+DATETIME%29%2C%27%27JKT-PAR%27%27%2C%27%27JKTB009%27%27%2C%27%27NNNN%27%27%2C%27%27urgent%2Fnourgent%27%27%2CCAST%28%27%272014-09-06+09%3A30%3A29%27%27+as+DATETIME%29%2C%27%27PARWIS%27%27%2CNULL%2CCAST%28%27%272014-09-13+09%3A30%3A29%27%27+as+DATETIME%29%2C%27%27SHIMIZU%27%27%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL

Comment: yes that's what i did, then i invoke that url, nothing happened, it doesn't event execute my webservice and it doesn't give me error too.. no failed web request or another error in my debuging mode. any another solution?